# Cann't connect to 'Other Locations' on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, files, sftp

I'm trying to connect to a sftp server in Files-application via Other Locations -> Connect to Server.

Every URL gets red immediately after entering ':' after the protocol (happens with every protocoltype not just sftp). (sftp OK; sftp: already red)

I can connect to the sftp server via terminal and from Files on Ubuntu 22.04 (running as vm)

How can I fix that or at least debug it further?

[image: Connectionbar with red URL]

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem. I booted from Ubuntu 20.04 ISO in a VM using the Try Ubuntu option. I entered the IP address of my computer as you have done, `sftp://192.168.0.127`. I got a notice about unknown host, and if I wanted to continue. Then I got an access denied error, as password based login is disabled in that host. I only got the "red URL" when I typed `fstp://192.168.0.127` by mistake. Make sure the `openssh-client` is installed in your Ubuntu 20.04 desktop computer.

Comment: Thanks
openssh-client is installed.
Reinstalled nautilus  -> it started working again

Answer (score 2):

reinstalled nautilus with apt
`sudo apt remove nautilus`
`sudo apt install nautilus`